# Filter date not between two dates

Tags: swift, realm

Using `Realm 2.7.0` and `Swift 3`, my application tries to filter a object based on its date, returning all dates that are NOT between two given dates.

Given a `Object` called `Model`, it has an variable called date (type `NSDate`).

Currently, I am using this code to filter:

```
realm.objects(Model.self)
  .filter("NOT date BETWEEN %@", [today, twoDaysAgo])
```

But it is returning all data, the filter is not working.

Thank you.

Comment: try date NOT BETWEEN %@

Comment: NSInvalidArgumentException

Comment: Ok try this .filter("NOT (date BETWEEN %@)", [today, towDaysAgo])

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
realm.objects(Model.self)
  .filter("NOT (date BETWEEN %@)", [today, twoDaysAgo])
```

Comment: Working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try this predicate query

let predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "!(date BETWEEN %@ , %@)", today, twoDaysAgo)

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "!(date BETWEEN %@ , %@)"'